# Semantic Ui Dropdown on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I want my semantic ui dropdown menu to trigger on hover instead of click, it works on click, but not hover.

**Javascript:**

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({on:'hover'});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ui dropdown item">
    <i class="fa fa-users"></i> Members <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    <div class="menu">
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Players</a>
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> Staff</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want hover effect to open dropdown menu then you don't need to use javascript, instead you can add class `simple` to your parent `div`:

```
<div class="ui simple dropdown item">
    <i class="fa fa-users"></i> Members <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    <div class="menu">
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Players</a>
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> Staff</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BJyQ7/30/)**

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to keep the transition?

Comment: if I don't user simple, when I click it drops down with a transition. I need a way to have it dropdown on hover with a transition.

Comment: I think `SemUI` is not support this feature at this moment or maybe I'm missing something. Sorry to say so... :/

Answer (score 4):

This is the same answer as above, just cleaner.

```
$('.dropdown').dropdown({transition: 'drop', on: 'hover' });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can take this, it works for me

`$('.dropdown').dropdown({transition: 'drop' }).dropdown({ on: 'hover' });`

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
$('.menu > .ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    on: 'hover'
});
```

And it works well. On your case, try to select the parent of dropdown item.