# Semantic-ui dropdown still doesnt work after js added

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

I am trying to build a site with semantic ui and i have problem with dropdown menu. I have read another questions and the solution is adding js. I already did but dropdown still doesnt work

here is my code. what am i doing wrong

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Semantic Ui</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">


</head>

<body>



    <div id="navbar" class="ui stackable menu">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/images/logo.png">
      </div>
      <a class="item active" href="">Page1</a>

      <div class="ui  dropdown item">
          Dropdown
          <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          <div class="menu">
            <div class="item">Drop 1</div>
            <div class="item">Drop 2</div>
            <div class="item">Drop 3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <a class="item" href="">Page2</a>
      <a class="item" href="">Page3</a>
      <a class="item" href="">Page4</a>
    </div>


  <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You have to add Jquery ($)

```
<div id="heroes-dropdown" class="ui simple dropdown">
<div class="text">Heroes</div>
<i class="dropdown icon"></i>
<div class="menu">
    <a class="item"><i class="edit icon"></i> Edit Profile</a>
    <a class="item"><i class="globe icon"></i> Choose Language</a>
    <a class="item"><i class="settings icon"></i> Account Settings</a>
</div>
```

This is what you looking for (example)

Comment: Now dropdown works but why should i click this to open? Could be done with just hovering?

Comment: @Dion add class "simple" to your parent div. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250093/semantic-ui-dropdown-on-hover